# How do make Cmd + S files save to the file I opened with numbers with its existing format/extension?

Tags: mac, numbers

I usually open *.XLSX* files with **Numbers** for quick edit.

However doing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> makes **Numbers** prompt to save the file with *.numbers* extension. How do I override this behavior?

Comment: You can’t make Numbers save in Excel format by default. You could re-export the file to Excel format once you are done but, unless it is a simple spreadsheet, the re-exported file may look quite different than the original Excel file even if you make very few changes in Numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numbers does not open Excel files directly. A new Numbers document is created.

- Numbers can convert Excel files to Numbers documents when opened, which is a lossy process, and
- Numbers can export to Excel, which is a lossy process.

Since both steps are lossy, it’s required to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you must have **excel** to save a file into excel type, but you could change the extension back to *.xlsx* with **finder** or use the *export into* menu (inside the *file* menu)

[image]

Comment: I know Numbers can export the file as XLSX that is why I am wondering why it can just overwrite the file I just opened...